# Element is not working for transitions in css3

Tags: css, animation, vuejs2, css-transitions, transform

I'm new to css3 animations m doing is have a vertical  menu  which is hidden then on click of the button m rotating it using the Y axis making it visible but both the left and right border is rotating

My need is vertical  menu  which is hidden on click of the button  rotate it using the Y axis making it visible out-to -in rotate just the right border i wanna rotate only the right side of border keeping the left side border  stiff  to screen height and  on  click of the button   the menu bar must fade in-to-out  completely this wanna do it using css3 or js

m using vue js to toggle

following is my code

```
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   align-items: stretch; 
   perspective: 1500px;    
 }
 .sideBar{
   border: 1px solid black;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 40%;
   transition:transform .8s ease-in-out;
   animation-name: fadeOut;   
  }
 .sideBarHvr{        
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
  }
```

this is the html n css3 to apply onto it

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="sideBar" v-bind:class="[showSideBar?'sideBarHvr':'']" >            
    </nav>      
            <div class="container-fluid">                    
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click='toggleSideBar' id="barCollapse">
                         <i class="fa fa-bars" ></i>
                    </button>                    
            </div>            
   </div>
```

any help is appreciated and please explain the transition , transform and animation how its inter related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.wrapper {
display: flex;
align-items: stretch; 
perspective: 1500px;    
 }
 .sideBar{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20%;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.945, 0.020, 0.270, 0.665);
  transform-origin: center left; /* Set the transformed position of sidebar to center left side. */
  background: teal; 
 }
 .sideBarHvr{ 
  margin-left: -330px;       
  transform: rotateY(100deg);
  }
```